# C: Table-Spreadsheet Data structure

Tags: c, data-structures, structure, spreadsheet, typedef

I would like to make a dynamic data structure that can read and store a simple spreadsheet.
I made one structure that stores a cell, structure for one row where I store pointer to every cell in that row and structure for whole table with pointers to rows.

```
typedef struct cell{
  int ceLen;
  char *cont;
}*Cell;

typedef struct {
  int clsinRow;
  Cell *row;
}Row;

typedef struct {
  int rwsinTab;
  Row *tab;
}Table;
```

I wrote a simple code to test row structure, but it looks like it doesn't work.

```
  char *str1[5] = {"r1c1", "r1c2", "r1c3", "r1c4", "r1c5"}; // Cells content for test purpose only

  Row *r;
  r->clsinRow = 5; //Num of cells in row

  for(int i=0; i<r->clsinRow; i++){
    Cell c = (Cell) malloc(sizeof(struct cell)); //Allocate the space for one cell 
    strcpy(c->cont, str1[i]); 
    
    r->row[i] = c;
  }

  for(int i=0; i<r->clsinRow; i++){
    printf("%s\t", r->row[i]->cont);
  }
```

I'm not sure if this structure was properly implemented and if I should better use some other data structure for this problem(like linked list or hash table).
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Out of curiosity `clsinRow` what kind of naming convention is that? Why not just `row_count`? what does `clsin` stand for? `typedef *Cell` - typedef pointers are (almost) always a bad idea, do not use it. It is confusing, as it is in your case - `Cell *row;` is a double pointer. `Row *r;
  r->` - is invalid - `r` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

At first you don't allocate any space for the Row variable. You have to allocate memory, just like you do with the Cell.

But,even if you fix it there is a problem with your strcpy.At that point the c->cont, which is a char pointer is NULL. So, strcpy is having a hard time coping the string and it return segfault.

I would advice you to make a different function where you allocate everything that need to be allocated and you return a cell pointer (Cell). Then you give this pointer to the c variable and hopefully, it will work.